# Plug-and-play API for detecting/interfacing Flash drive insertions?

Tags: windows, api, disk, plug-and-play

Is there a way to provide a call to a user-defined program after a plug-and-play flash drive has been inserted and detected by Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Microsoft finally figured out that autorun programs are a huge security risk, and no longer will start an application when a drive is inserted.

However, an application that's already installed and running can be notified when a drive is inserted.  Is that sufficient?  Look up [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480.aspx) and specifically the `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` w/`DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME` case.